# Okay to catch UnsatisfiedLinkError to fall back to a different DLL on a call to System.LoadLibrary?

Tags: java

At startup, I want my Java program to load a DLL that should be on the path defined by java.library.path. However, if that DLL is missing, I want my program to fall back to loading a different DLL. System.LoadLibrary throws an UnsatisfiedLinkError if it can't find the DLL file. UnsatisfiedLinkError is a subclass of Error, not of Exception. Lots of commentary suggests that it is bad practice to catch Error. Is this a case where it is okay to do something like this?

```
try
{
    System.loadLibrary("myLibrary");
}
catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e)
{
    try
    {
        System.load(<a fully qualified path to my fall-back library>);
    }
    catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e)
    {
        <report that even the fall-back library didn't load>;
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I'd say that was perfectly acceptable - but I might put a bit of diagnostic logging in there to indicate that an attempt was being made to use the backup library

Comment: @DaveHowes: Thanks. Agreed that actual practice would call for more informative handling. Problem stems from the fact that I don't know where `loadLibary` will look, so I can't use something as straightforward as `File.exists` to avoid the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` in the first place. Could probably write something based on the `loadLibrary` source, but I wouldn't even think twice about this as an issue if `UnsatisfiedLinkError` were a subclass of `Exception` instead of `Error`. Impression I get is that some folks are pretty hard-core about _never_ catching `Error`.

Comment: Some rules are made to be broken :)

Comment: So true. But, to read what some others have said about catching Error objects, you'd think the policy against doing so would have been carved in stone tablets.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In this case it's perfectly acceptable. In fact it's the only way to do what you want to do.

In general it's bad practice to catch Errors  because there is nothing you can do to recover from them and the application may be in an unpredictable state afterwards. For example `OutOfMemoryError` means you have run out of memory and there's very little you can do about it. `StackOverflowError` means that your call stack has grown too deep and there's not a lot you can do about that either.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I gleaned from the documentation: Error tends to mean the program can't recover. This seems like an odd Throwable to put into that category. That is, it suggests to me that UnsatisfiedLinkError isn't the right thing for loadLibrary to throw. The UnsatisfiedLinkError doc says it is, "thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared native," but the loadLibrary doc says it throws UnsatisfiedLinkError "if the library does not exist." Not quite the same thing, imho, since it _is_ possible to recover in that situation.

Comment: True, you would think that loadLibrary should throw some kind of an Exception rather than an Error.

Comment: Joni, I'm marking your answer "accepted," since: a) it's the only one I got; b) it makes perfect sense to me; and c) I looked at your Web site and can tell right away you know what you're talking about. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm... interesting wrinkle just developed: I tried the above in actual practice and, when I start my code from the command line and it needs to fall back to the second try, it works. When I start it via double-click, the program runs and it informs me it will have to use the fall-back, but a number of run-time bugs show up. Here's the wrinkly bit: when I move my DLL to C:\windows\system32 and run via double-click, all those bugs go away and it runs just fine. More info when I figure it out...

Comment: I've just found that loading a native library from two different classloaders also throws UnsatisfiedLinkError: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#library_version

Comment: Ah. This is more complicated than we might at first have thought.

Comment: I read the page you linked to. Pretty detailed stuff. A point that caught my attention was the discussion about JNI_OnLoad. I am using JDK 1.6.0_30. javah doesn't automatically create a JNI_OnLoad function. I wonder if adding that would help, as it appears to activate features in the JVM that allow independent class loaders to load native libraries without affecting each other. I suppose the real answer would be found in the JVM source itself, but life's not that long, eh?

Comment: In general it's bad practice to catch Errors? What?

Comment: Yes, @joaquin. "An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch." http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html

Comment: Oh, I'm really sorry @Joni! I confused errors with exceptions. You're right.